# Variadic templates have duplicate symbols in object files?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic-templates, nm

I have the following test program:

```
#include <cstdio>

template<int i, int j, int k>
struct Dispatcher {
  template<typename... F>
  static inline void call1(bool a, bool b, int* output, F...) {
    *output = i;
    if (a) *output += j;
    if (b) *output += k;
  }

  template<typename F>
  static inline void call2(bool a, bool b, int* output, F) {
    *output = i;
    if (a) *output += j;
    if (b) *output += k;
  }
};


int main() {
  int output;
  Dispatcher<1, 2, 3>::call1(true, false, &output, 1337);
  printf("%i\n", output);
  Dispatcher<1, 2, 3>::call2(true, false, &output, 1337);
  printf("%i\n", output);
  return 0;
}
```

The program builds and runs as expected, but "nm -C" shows that it contains the following symbols:

```
000000000040065a W void Dispatcher<1, 2, 3>::call1<int>(bool, bool, int*, int)
000000000040065a W void Dispatcher<1, 2, 3>::call1<int>(bool, bool, int*, int)
00000000004006a4 W void Dispatcher<1, 2, 3>::call2<int>(bool, bool, int*, int)
```

Without unmangling, they are:

```
000000000040065a W _ZN10DispatcherILi1ELi2ELi3EE5call1IIiEEEvbbPiDpT_
000000000040065a W _ZN10DispatcherILi1ELi2ELi3EE5call1IJiEEEvbbPiDpT_
00000000004006a4 W _ZN10DispatcherILi1ELi2ELi3EE5call2IiEEvbbPiT_
```

Why does the function "call1" show up twice but "call2" shows up only once?  It looks like it has something to do with the variadic template argument...

I am building using gcc version 4.8.5 with the "-std=c++11 -O0" flags.  (I get the issue even with -03 in my real code but the test program gets inlined without -O0.)

Comment: No repro with gcc8 and clang6, so looks like an issue with your dated compiler.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look!  I can't reproduce with clang 3.7.1 either.  I wonder, is this a cosmetic issue with the older compilers, or is it really duplicating the whole function?

Comment: Honestly, I'm not sure; that's more low level than my usual field of expertise. Anyway, unless the binary size gets problematic, does it even matter?

Comment: You can check using objdump whether the function is duplicated `objdump -S a.out | c++filt -n`. I also cannot reproduce the issue.

Comment: Won't they get ditched after linking?

Comment: @PaoloCrosetto thanks for your suggestion - looks like it isn't duplicated.  call1 and call2 both show up only once and have the same instructions except call2 has an "xchg   %ax,%ax" after "retq" for some reason.  This answers my practical question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@BaummitAugen and @PaoloCrosetto pointed me in the right direction - this is apparently an issue restricted to older versions of gcc and it does not appear to actually increase the size of the compiled executable.